# 816G (indian dual sim) no rom installed, only cwm-recovery

Tags: htc-desire-816-dual

I searched for a solution to this problem since yesterday, but without any success so far.

My situation is the following:
I bought a HTC 816G (MT6592) with no rom installed. Only thing accessible is CWM recovery.

When I want to charge the phone, it shows a battery icon idicating that it's being charged and then reboots and shows it again. It does this over and over again with seemingly no progress in the charging process.

When I unplug it and try boot it normally, it shows a "Mi.com" icon, but then reboots again and again.

The only thing I can do is booting to recovery. Even though it does not seem to be charing, I can still operate the recovery mode without it being plugged in to a charger.

In the recovery it says "rua1 CWM v.5.5.0.4 for HTC Desire 816G d" at the top of the screen and "CWM automade 03.01.2016 01:12:51" at the bottom of the screen.
From there I tried installing roms which either failed to install or did not boot up properly after successful installation.

In the recovery menu under "advanced" and then "show log" it says:

> ro.hardware=mt6592
>
> ro.revision=0
>
> ro.emmc=0
>
> sys.usb.vid=0BB4
>
> init.svc.recovery=running
>
> sys.usb.config=mass_storage.adb
>
> service.adb.root=1
>
> init.svc.adbd=restarting
>
> sys.usb.state=mass_storage.adb

I appreciate any advice, I just want to have this phone operational.
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/desire-816/help/816g-indian-dual-sim-rom-installed-cwm-t3302234

Basically, the backcover needs to be removed and the battery needs to disconnected in order to prevent a bootloop when connected to the pc via usb cable.

Flash this rom (http://www.needrom.com/download/htc-desire-816g-dual-sim/) using the SP Flash Tool for mt6592 (for example this tutorial: http://bm-smartphone-reviews.blogspot.de/2014/05/mt6592-flashing-tutorial.html)

Good luck